# how do i change the selected row in a UIPickerview to a String(text)?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have put a `UIPickerView` for the user to select how they are feeling; annoyed, happy, sad etc. However I cannot convert what they have selected to a string or text. Is it possible to do this? If not how can I save the row/option they have selected in the picker?

Comment: Check out the UIPickerViewDelegate https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate

Comment: What issue exactly are you having? Update your question with some relevant code showing your issue.

Comment: How are you "saving" the selected row?  NSNumber inside an Array? mySQL? Other?? Bc I have something exactly what you're asking, conveniently :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, here's what is needed. Check out the project at this [gitHub](https://github.com) [commit](https://github.com/LinnierGames/Overstack/tree/d54409d90bdc4fd059041b1d53aa1267a6b19bc9) or [download zip](https://github.com/LinnierGames/Overstack/archive/d54409d90bdc4fd059041b1d53aa1267a6b19bc9.zip).

1. **Using `typedef enum`:** create a enumeration that holds all values of emotions; happy, okay, neutral, sad, unhappy, etc. All with unique values assigned to each one like so:

**Header File**

```
//Number Values for each value of emotion. Add new emotions to the bottom of list, sort will not
//be effected in this declartion
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    CTEmotionNone = 0,
    CTEmotionHappy = 1,
    CTEmotionOkay = 2,
    CTEmotionNeutral = 3,
    CTEmotionSad = 4,
    CTEmotionUnhappy = 5,
    CTEmotionVeryHappy = 6

} CDEmotions;
```

2. **Translating Number Values to text:** There's different ways to doing this part but i liked this. Create an inline method, or function, that will return a string for the corresponding value of emotion:

**Header File**

```
//Here is where the title for each number value will be transalated
static inline NSString * NSEmotionTitleForEmotion( CDEmotions emotion) {
    switch (emotion) {
        case CTEmotionNone:
            return @"Empty"; break;
        case CTEmotionVeryHappy:
            return @"Very Happy"; break;
        case CTEmotionHappy:
            return @"Happy"; break;
        case CTEmotionOkay:
            return @"Okay"; break;
        case CTEmotionNeutral:
            return @"Neutral"; break;
        case CTEmotionSad:
            return @"Sad"; break;
        case CTEmotionUnhappy:
            return @"Unhappy"; break;

    }

}
```

3. **Now the Order:** creating another inline method, but this time returning an array with the order you want to display the emotions:

**Header File**

```
//Sorted int values in this array. Sort will be shown here. Do not put text in here, because then
//to know what "Very Happy" is you'll ahve to compare it to a string vs just saying 1 == 1, that
//means CTEmotionHappy
static inline NSArray * NSEmotionsList() {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            @(CTEmotionNone),
            @(CTEmotionVeryHappy),
            @(CTEmotionHappy),
            @(CTEmotionOkay),
            @(CTEmotionNeutral),
            @(CTEmotionSad),
            @(CTEmotionUnhappy), nil];

}
```

Now using these functions will be fun :) I'll do it in your case using `- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` from the UIPickerViewDataSource:

**ViewController.h**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [NSEmotionsList() count];

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return NSEmotionTitleForEmotion( [[NSEmotionsList() objectAtIndex: row] intValue]);

}
```

And lastly implement the delegate method `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [labelEmotion setText: NSEmotionTitleForEmotion( [[NSEmotionsList() objectAtIndex: row] intValue])];

}
```